# Localization for UITextView in storyboard

Tags: ios, localization, interface-builder, uitextview

So I have an application with different buttons, labels and some Text Views in storyboard where I entered the text directly in the storyboard. I enabled base localization and added a couple of languages.

This generated storyboards for Base (English) and the other languages with a list of items objectIDs.
I translated everything, and the labels and buttons (ALL OF THEM) work and show in the language I set the device to.

The text fields however keep showing the initial English text no matter which language I set...
Are there any extra steps involved for Text View?

Comment: I just now ran into the EXACT same issue. Everything works fine in the simulator except UITextViews when using strings for the localized languages. It DOES work as expected when I switch to IB storyboard files, btw. Xcode5 and Mavericks.

Comment: Same here. Weird issue! Let's hope someone knows a workaround/fix... I too xxode 5/maverick...

Comment: Just tested on devices (iPhone5c and iPad), and it's the same problem. So it's not just the simulator.

Comment: BTW, where you localizing for a right to left language by any chance? I am also trying to figure out how to automatically change text orientation for a given locale...

Comment: You should post this as a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I did some research, and it seems that in order for this to work correctly, the text for the UITextView needs to be set programmatically.

Source: [Devforums.apple](https://devforums.apple.com/message/883759#883759)

Quote:

> as I understand it, strings such as the text property of a text view/field have to be set in code using NSLocalizedString. The first 1/2 hour of WWDC 2013 video session #219 Making Your App World Ready covers this if you have the time to watch it

So, it seems that the workaround (if you don't want to set the text programmatically) is to convert the strings file into a storyboard before shipping the app. This does seem to work as intended and shows the UITextView properly localized.

EDIT: Found another workaround that allows to keep .strings file.

In `- (void)viewDidLoad`:

```
for(UIView* v in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        UITextView* txv = (UITextView*)v;
        NSString *loctxt = [txv.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        txv.text = NSLocalizedString(loctxt, @"");
    }
}
```

This produces a Percent Escapes encoded string from whatever is inside the storyboard, like this:

```
Hello%20World
```

In your `Localizable.strings` file, you use the above as the key, and this will produce the localized text in the app at runtime for the selected locale, like this:

```
"Hello%20World" = "Hallo Welt";
```

The Percent escaping takes care of all escape characters in the base string.

Comment: Edited reply to add a workaround that allows to keep .strings file

Answer (score 2):

As my comment on Dmitry's answer cannot be formatted nicely, I repeat this as an answer here. The Swift version of his solution looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let tv = view as? UITextView, ident = view.restorationIdentifier {
            tv.text = NSLocalizedString("\(ident).text", tableName: "Main", comment: "")
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

(Note that in Swift, `NSLocalizedString` replaces several Objective-C macros, one of them being `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`)

P.S.: Unfortunately, in iOS 10 this seems not to work any more. Instead, the call gives back the id that was supplied as first parameter (e.g. "`abc-xy-pqr.text`"). Any ideas?

Comment: `restorationIdentifier` returned `nil` for me. I just set the Restoration Identifier of the Text View to its Object ID and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, I have solved this problem a different way, this will allow you to still use the SAME .Strings file that is generated by Xcode for storyboards.

There are two parts to this solution:

In the .m file for your view add this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(UIView* view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] && view.restorationIdentifier)
        {
            UITextView* textView = (UITextView*)view;
            NSString *textViewName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.text",textView.restorationIdentifier];
            textView.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(textViewName, @"Main", nil);
           //change this to be the same as the name of your storyboard ^^^
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and in your storyboard in the identity inspector copy the "Object ID" to the "Restoration ID" field.

This will apply the new localized text to all of your UITextViews on screen load and will allow you to use the already generated strings files.

Comment: This is a very handy solution. In Swift, the `for` loop looks like `for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let tv = view as? UITextView, ident = view.restorationIdentifier {
            let textViewName = String(format: "%@.text", ident);
            tv.text = NSLocalizedString(textViewName, tableName: "Main", comment: "")
        }
    }` (Note that in Swift, `NSLocalizedString` replaces several Obj-C macros, one of them being `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`)

Comment: Unfortunately, in iOS 10 this seems not to work any more. Instead, the call gives back the id that was supplied as first parameter (e.g. "abc-xy-pqr.text"). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I made my own Categories for the components.

For example, a button:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface LocalizedButton : UIButton
@end

#import "LocalizedButton.h"

@implementation LocalizedButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    NSLog(@"Loading LocalizedButton: initWithCoder");
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
        [self localizeButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    NSLog(@"Loading LocalizedButton: initWithFrame");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       [self localizeButton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) localizeButton{
    self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    NSString* text = NSLocalizedString(self.titleLabel.text, nil);
    [self setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [self setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

@end
```

You can se the complete code on: https://github.com/exmo/equizmo-ios/blob/master/Quiz/LocalizedButton.m

Comment: So, you can use on xcode the text from your Strings. Just select the class LocalizedButton.

Comment: Buttons? Who said anything about buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The Swift solution of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950945/stefan works for me on iOS 10.2 when I replace the "Main" with the correct id (e.g. "MainStoryboard") which references the localized file id.storyboard (e.g. "MainStoryboard.storyboard")